# implement the demosaic function in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've got a matrix file which is a photo changed by the Bayer filter. when I use the demosaic function on it using RGGB sensor alignment, it turns into the original picture.
I tried to implement the demosaic function myself by putting the mean of the same-color pixels around each unavailable pixel color as its value but the answer it gives is not the original photo. can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
clear;
clc;

I = struct2cell(load('Bayer.mat'));
J = I{1,1};
[M N] = size(J);
T = uint8(zeros(M,N,3));

for i = 2:M-1
    for j = 2:N-1
        if mod(i,2) ~= mod(j,2) %G
            T(i,j,1)=round((J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/2);
            T(i,j,2)=round(J(i,j));
            T(i,j,3)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j))/2);
        elseif mod(i,2) == 1 %R
            T(i,j,1)=round(J(i,j));
            T(i,j,2)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j)+J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/4);
            T(i,j,3)=round((J(i-1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i-1,j+1))/4);
        else %B
            T(i,j,1)=round((J(i-1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i-1,j+1))/4);
            T(i,j,2)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j)+J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/4);
            T(i,j,3)=round(J(i,j));
        end
    end
end
%K = demosaic(J,'rggb');
imwrite(J,'im0.jpg');
imwrite(T,'im05.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake while processing green channel. You should consider bottom left and right top greens separately, because its neighbors change for each case. Here is the following code:

```
I = imread('lena.bmp');
[M,N,L] = size(I);
J = zeros(M,N);
R = I(:,:,1);
G = I(:,:,2);
B = I(:,:,3);
J(1:2:M,1:2:N) = R(1:2:M,1:2:N);
J(2:2:M,2:2:N) = B(2:2:M,2:2:N);
J(J==0) = G(J==0);
T = zeros(M,N,3);
figure,imshow(uint8(J));

%% Reconstruct Bayer Filtered Image here
for i = 2:M-1
    for j = 2:N-1
        if mod(i,2) == 0 && mod(j,2) == 1 %G
            T(i,j,1)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j))/2);
            T(i,j,2)=round(J(i,j));
            T(i,j,3)=round((J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/2);
        elseif mod(i,2) == 1 && mod(j,2) == 0
            T(i,j,1)=round((J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/2);
            T(i,j,2)=round(J(i,j));
            T(i,j,3)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j))/2);
        elseif mod(i,2) == 1 %R
            T(i,j,1)=round(J(i,j));
            T(i,j,2)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j)+J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/4);
            T(i,j,3)=round((J(i-1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i-1,j+1))/4);
        else %B
            T(i,j,1)=round((J(i-1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i+1,j-1)+J(i-1,j+1))/4);
            T(i,j,2)=round((J(i-1,j)+J(i+1,j)+J(i,j-1)+J(i,j+1))/4);
            T(i,j,3)=round(J(i,j));
        end
    end
end
```

Also, if your image `J` is defined as `uint8` you should make it `double`, since `uint8` will overflow when sum of the pixels exceeds 255.

Comment: the picture I get in the input as I is an N*M*1 bayer matrix so I don't understand where you got the ```I(:,:,2)``` and ```I(:,:,3)``` from
then I have to change it to to the original which ```K = demosaic(T,'rggb');``` would do it but I'm not allowed to use the demosaic function so my main problem is implementing demosaic on the N*M*1 matrix

Comment: @AlalehA Here I is the original RGB image(dimension = M x N x 3) it is Bayer filtered and saved to T matrix(M x N x 1). Then another RGB image K(MxNx3) is constructed from T matrix using demosaic function.